# How can I find last row that contains string in txt with cmd command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I want to find two different strings in .txt file. I need two scripts, first script to find last row that contains these strings together and second script to find last row that contains these strings seperately. I tried to write somethings but I go off the project.

This what i have tried so far as code :

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< deneme.txt') do set /a lines=%%i
echo %lines%
set /a startLine=%lines% - 1
more /e +%startLine% deneme.txt > temp.txt
find "ali" temp.txt|find "veli" 
del temp.txt
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, and explain how it's not working.

Comment: for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< deneme.txt') do set /a lines=%%i
echo %lines%
set /a startLine=%lines% - 1
more /e +%startLine% deneme.txt > temp.txt
find "ali" temp.txt|find "veli"
del temp.txt

Comment: You need to prove that you have tried something before asking for help in this forum.

Comment: As I said go off the project, I wrote a script that finds strings at last row. Bu I want to find last row that contains these strings.

Comment: Please post an example input file, and the command, and a clear description of what you expect the output to be, and what the output actually is --- in your main post, not a comment. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "string1=ali"
set "string2=veli"
set "file=deneme.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i "\<%string1%\>" %file% ^|findstr /i /v "\<%string2%\>" ') do set "out1=%%a"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i "\<%string2%\>" %file% ^|findstr /i /v "\<%string1%\>" ') do set "out2=%%a"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i "\<%string1%\>" %file% ^|findstr /i "\<%string2%\>" ') do set "out3=%%a"

echo last line with %string1%:   "%out1%"
echo last line with %string2%:   "%out2%"
echo last line with both:        "%out3%"
```

for explanations, see `for /?` and `findstr /?`